# kendo combobox clear button is not working with android 9

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, android-9.0-pie, kendo-combobox

clear button is not working with android 9

i checked with other android device but all below version with working nice. only for android 9 version is not working

please check and let us know if any found solution

step:1. search any text(for ex. item)

2. and check clear button display right side middle in textbox
3. click on clear button but currently not working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/events">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css">
    <script src="../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>ComboBox</h4>
        <input id="combobox" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h4>Console log</h4>
        <div class="console"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function onOpen() {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    kendoConsole.log("event :: open");
                }
            }

            function onClose() {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    kendoConsole.log("event :: close");
                }
            }

            function onChange() {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    kendoConsole.log("event :: change");
                }
            }

            function onSelect(e) {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    if (e.dataItem) {
                        var dataItem = e.dataItem;
                        kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.text + " : " + dataItem.value + ")");
                    } else {
                        kendoConsole.log("event :: select");
                    }
                }
            };

            function onDataBound(e) {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    kendoConsole.log("event :: dataBound");
                }
            };

            function onFiltering(e) {
                if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                    kendoConsole.log("event :: filtering");
                }
            }

            var data = [
                { text: "Item 1", value: "1" },
                { text: "Item 2", value: "2" },
                { text: "Item 3", value: "3" }
            ];

            $("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                filter: "startswith",
                dataSource: data,
                select: onSelect,
               minLength: 2,
                    autoBind: true, //this is important
                
                 
                 
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code snippet works like a charm with the latest Firefox and Chrome on my Google Pixel with Android 9. I doubt that it is an issue with Android but with the browser you are using. Maybe you've installed some addons which prevent the application from working properly?

Comment: Window platform( Firefox and Chrome) working fine but i used this code in my cordova app. 

Please install https://i.diawi.com/9CLnGN this app and see

Answer (score 2):

Please update

```
kendo.all.min.js 
kendo.mobile.all.min.css
kendo.mobile.min.js
```

issue might be for older version if you update it issue will get  resolved

To latest version and kendo combobox clear button will work with android 9